# Excel: running maximum of two rows, or just return value in one row

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet:

| Name | Grade |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | 82 |
| Name1 | 90 |
| Name2 | 65 |
| Name3 | 90 |
| Name3 | 60 |

I would like an Excel command that will do the following in a new column (TrueGrade, column C):

If a string occurs twice in column A (Name)
then get the maximum of the two values from column B (Grade)
else get the value from column B in the same row as the name (which only occurs once).

This is what the result should look like:

| Name | Grade | TrueGrade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 82 | 90 |
| Name1 | 90 |  |
| Name2 | 65 | 65 |
| Name3 | 90 | 90 |
| Name3 | 60 |  |

Unfortunately, vlookup does not return multiple values.

So far, I have tried this in cell C2:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$B$5, SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$5=B2, ROW($A$2:$A$5)), ROW(1:1))-1,COLUMNS($A$2:$B$5))
```

which gave me 82, but this is just the first instance of a grade for Name1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your test data as an example, putting this formula in C2 and copying down gave me your expected results:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)>1,"",MAXIFS(B$2:B$6,A$2:A$6,A2))
```

Obviously extend the ranges to suit your situation.  Also note that the CountIF formula range is slightly different than the Maxifs formula.  This also assumes you have the MaxIfS formula. If you don't you can do the same thing with an array formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)>1,"",MAX(IF(A2=A2:A6,B2:B6)))
```

Just remember to confirm the array formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `SUMPRODUCT` in these cases (because I always forget to properly enter array formulas).

So in cell C2, you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$2:$A$6=A2)*($B$2:$B$6)))
```

> EDIT: late with the updated answer based on my earlier work but it's the same as @sous2817:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(OFFSET($A$2,0,0,ROW()-ROW($A$2)+1,1),$A2)=1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$2:$A$6=A2)*($B$2:$B$6))),"")
```

This still works without an array formula.

Comment: Thanks PeterT, but that returns the same value in both C2 and C3. For example, I'd like to leave cell C3 blank, because cell C2 is the maximum grade for Name1. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you can, you could use the @PeterT's formula but first delete the duplicate names, so you get that you want...